# How to install Kivent in qpython?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, qpython3

Is it possible to install kivent in qpython for Android? Kivy is installed but I can't seem to find a way to install kivent

Answer (score 0):

Kivent is one of the Kivy sister projects which is also using Cython (way more than Kivy itself I'd say), therefore you definitely need to cross-compile it to Android.

By default (non-qpython approach) you can either create a Kivy Launcher([1](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/launcher/), [2](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/testapps/testlauncher_setup/sdl2.py)) with `kivent` as a dependency or assemble a separate app (not editable unfortunately).

QPython app has some kind of [package index](http://qpypi.qpython.org/search/)(like PyPI) which from what I've heard should work from the phone side, however I don't see `kivent` anywhere, therefore I think it's not possible to install `kivent` to qpython app until the guys who maintain the package index cross-compile it and upload for the common users.

Also, there's some kind of ["component"](http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/how-to-start/#how-to-install-3rd-libraries) thingy which is mentioned together with C/C++ libs, however the link is [empty](http://wiki.qpython.org/hack/make_component/).

Comment: I did a quick search but most of them require me to use a computer to first compile the library in a computer. My computer is currently having issues. Is it possible to compile the libraries in my phone itself? Also, I do not have such a great technical knowledge of how to assemble a seperate app using kivy launcher and kivent in it. Could you elaborate? Thanks in advance